# System.out.println function syntax in C++

Tags: java, c++, println

I want to create a function in C++ using cout that has the same as the println function in java. This means that the call should be something like this:

```
int a=5
println("A string" + a);
```

the variable a should have any basic type. 
What kind of parameter should I have in this case and how would it work?

Thanks

Comment: Template is your friend.

Comment: well this is obvious...but how do I take this values from the parameter and what kind of parameter should it be?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. `System.out.println` isn't what makes the `+` work.

Comment: In C and C++, when `a` is 5, `"A string" + a` is `"ing"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As larsmans already pointed out, java has overloads on the operator +. So you can concat strings with integer. This is also possible in C++ but not out of the box for all types.

You could use a templated functions like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void printer(T t) 
{ 
    cout << t << endl;
}

template <typename T, typename ...U>
void printer(T t, U ...u)
{
  cout << t;
  printer(u...);
}


int main()
{
  int a=5;
  printer("A string ", a);
  return 0;
}
```

But I would recommend to take a look at [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/). I guess this library will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Many are downvoting, but that's not going to explain why what you're asking is incorrect.

You have two choices here:

1. You can make a templated `println(T val)` function which takes any type you like, ints, doubles, etc, and you can print them in that function.
2. However, what you're requesting up there: `"A string" + a` this is an expression which will return a type. What you're doing here is adding a `const char*` and an `int`. This unfortunately isn't going to do anything like what you expect, it's going to do [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html), and in this particular case won't even compile. But for the general case, say a `std::string` and a class called `Foo`, the compiler will look for an [`operator+` overload](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/) which can concatenate those two things.

   Your second option, but slightly more dangerous, is to have a `println` function that either takes a `std::string` or `const char*` and to define all the different operator+ operations that you might want. I don't recommend this though, as the default operation between a pointer and an integer is to do pointer arithmetic, which is very useful.

I recommend starting with a template function, and seeing what happens from there.

Comment: Thank you Salgar, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

10 years later in C++23 there is a [`println` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/println) in the standard library.

```cpp
#include <print>

int main()
{
    int i = 5;

    std::println("Hello, World {}!", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Since C++23 is quite new, it will be hard to find compiler support at the moment.